# Line integral $\int_K \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

**Solve** $\int_K \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy$ =?

**K:** $x^2+y^2=1$ **is oriented positively.**

---

My attempt:

$\int_K \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy = |x=cost, y=sint,x'=- sint,y'=cost | $ = *

I put for $dx = -sint,dy=cost$

*$= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{sint}{cost^2+sint^2} -sint -\frac{cost}{cost^2+sint^2} cost  dt=  -\int_0^{2\pi} 1 dt = - 2 \pi $*

We can't use Green's theorem because $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ aren't continuous and their diveratives aren't continuous at point. $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems ok. You can't use Green-Stokes because of the reason you correctly stated. Another way to see this result is to note that if $z = x+iy$ and ${\rm d}z = {\rm d}x+i\,{\rm d}y$, then $$\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\,{\rm d}x - \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,{\rm d}y = {\rm Im}\left(-\frac{{\rm d}z}{z}\right),$$and so $$ -{\rm Im} \int_{\Bbb S^1}\frac{{\rm d}z}{z} = -{\rm Im}(2\pi i) = -2\pi.$$

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is
$$\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy=-\dfrac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}=-d\left(\arctan\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$$
so
$$\int_K \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dx -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy=-\int_K  d\left(\arctan\dfrac{y}{x}\right)=-\int_0^{2\pi}dt=-2\pi$$